# How to use javascript modules to load prefs for Mozilla?

Tags: firefox-addon, preferences, thunderbird-addon

The other day I submitted an addon to Mozilla Addons for the preliminary review.  The reviewer gave me this recommendation:

> Use JavaScript modules where possible. These will only be imported if
>   they haven't been loaded yet and reduce memory consumption and
>   response times. See
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules and
>   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_code_modules/Services.jsm
>   . Services.prefs ... is interesting for you.

Now, I was using this to load my prefs:

var prefs = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/preferences-service;1"]
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIPrefBranch);

and later...

```
var mypref= this.prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.myaddon.mypref");
```

Now, I looked at the page references and am not sure how to do it the way the reviewer suggests.  I can't find an example of how to do it that way.  The best I could do was to add this:

```
Components.utils.import('resource://textlink-modules/prefs.js'),
```

...but I couldn't figure out how to refer to mypref after that.  I am new to addons, so if someone could help me out, that would be great.  How can I do it his way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't import your `prefs.js` as a module, because it isn't one.

What you can, and are encouraged to, do is import once the Services module and then reference the various services it offers through the global variable Services.

Edit:

```js
Components.utils.import("resource://gre/modules/Services.jsm");
var prefs = Services.prefs;
var mypref = prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.myaddon.mypref");
```

Comment: I understand that `prefs.js` isn't a module, but I got that example from MDN, and am rather confused. Would you be so kind as to post me an example?  I can't seem to figure it out from the documentation.

Comment: Finally, then, to get my pref, am I right to do this?: `var mypref=prefs.getBoolPref("extensions.myaddon.mypref");`

Comment: Okay, that IS it.  Marked Solved, and you get my vote, too for humouring me with the code snippet.